# Como comparar parte de strings em C?

Tags: c, string, comparação

Sei apenas comparar duas strings por inteiro em C, mas eu consigo comparar apenas parte de uma string? Queria desenvolver um programa que lê trechos de uma reclamação e baseado nesses trechos dê  uma sugestão de resposta. É possível ler apenas trechos em C? Em Java sei que é possível, mas gostaria de fazer em C. Obrigado.

Comment: Compara apenas uma parte ? Como assim ? Saber se uma string contem outra ? Sugiro que torne a sua pergunta mais clara adicionando exemplos dos resultados que esperaria ver entre algumas comparações

Comment: Vamos lá. Vamos supor que a variável "reclamacao" recebe o texto: "Gostaria de saber horários entre Rio de Janeiro x Aparecida". Gostaria de fazer algo do tipo.

Se na variável "reclamacao" conter a string "saber horários" retorne a String "Para visualizar horários entre no site..."

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usara função `strcasestr()` da biblioteca padrão `string.h` para verificar (sem considerar letras maiúsculas ou minúsculas) se uma string *está contida* em outra, por exemplo:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char reclamacao[] = "Gostaria de saber horarios entre Rio de Janeiro x Aparecida";

int main( void )
{
    if( strcasestr( reclamacao, "saber horarios" ) )
    {
        printf("Para visualizar horários entre no site...\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Não Encontrei!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ótimo amigo, é exatamente isso que eu gostaria. verificar se uma string está contida em outra. Muitíssimo obrigado.

Comment: Está dando erro na linha if( strcasestr( reclamacao, "saber horarios" ) ).
O erro é "[Error] 'strcasestr' was not declared in this scope"

Comment: @ErickNascimento: Corrigido :)

Answer (score 0):

Sim, é possivel.

Voce precisara usar a funcao `memcmp`.

Exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char buffer1[] = "DWgaOtP12df0";
  char buffer2[] = "DWGAOTP12DF0";

  int n;

  n = memcmp (buffer1, buffer2, sizeof(buffer1));

  if (n>0) printf ("'%s' is greater than '%s'.\n",buffer1,buffer2);
  else if (n<0) printf ("'%s' is less than '%s'.\n",buffer1,buffer2);
  else printf ("'%s' is the same as '%s'.\n",buffer1,buffer2);

  return 0;
}
```

Veja o [manual da funcao](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcmp.3.html) para maiores detalhes.